# Why can a Java static method call a constructor, but not refer to this?

Tags: java, constructor, static, instance

*My Assumptions*:

1. Static method cannot cannot call non-static methods.
2. Constructors are kind of a **method** with no return type.

Given this example...

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main p = new Main();  // constructor call
            k();  // [implicit] `this` reference
        }

        protected Main() {
            System.out.print("1234");
        }

        protected void k() {
        }
    }
```

- this line prints 1234: `Main p = new Main()`
- this line throws an Exception: `k()`

*Why did the example code do those two things? Don't they conflict with my above Assumptions?  Are my Assumptions correct?*

Comment: If it was impossible to call a constructor from a static method, then you could not construct any object ever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1 - Static method cannot cannot call non-static methods.

Sure they can, but they **need an object to call the method on**.

In a static method, there's no `this` reference available, so `foo()` (which is equivalent to `this.foo()`) is illegal.

> 2 - Constructors are kind of a method with no return type.

If they should be [compared to methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145700/can-we-say-contructors-are-methods-in-java), I would say **constructors are closer to non-static methods** (since there is indeed a `this` reference inside a constructor).

Given this view, it should be clear to you why a static method can call a constructor without any problems.

---

So, to sum it up:

```
Main p = new Main();
```

is okay, since `new Main()` does not rely on any existing object.

```
k();
```

is not okay since it is equivalent to `this.k()` and `this` is not available in your (static) main method.

Comment: What confuses people all the time is the fact that `new main()` is NOT a simple constructor call -- it is the application of the unary operator `new` while specifying which constructor to call **as a part of a much broader allocation+initialization procedure**.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, JLS reference?

Comment: Do you really need it, since it's obvious? Applying `new` **allocates memory from the heap** -- that's not written in the constructor, for one. It also calls **all instance initializers** -- another fact surely obvious to you. That's also not written anywhere in constructor code. It also calls the constructor with `this` suddenly defined -- not by the caller, but by implicit code. Constructor is nothing but a callback, really.

Comment: I'm asking because I suspect that you're making implementation specific assumptions regarding how Java is compiled and executed. Surely constructing an object involves running the instance initializers etc, but allocation procedure, how it ends up on something called the heap and how `this` suddenly materializes, I'm not sure is defined in the language specification. (I may be wrong though.)

Comment: OK, but the JLS also does not specify that `new X()` is a mere function call -- and that's the core of the point, since people routinely visualise it that way and make misguided comparisons to other types of functions in Java.

Answer (score 6):

No. Constructors aren't ordinary methods in this respect. The whole point of the constructor is to, well, construct a new instance of the class.

So it can be invoked in static scope too. Just think about it: if you needed an existing instance of your class in order to create a new instance of it, you would simply never be able to instantiate it ever.

A few clarifications:

> Static method cannot cannot call non-static methods.

Not quite. You can call a nonstatic method from inside a static method, just you need to *scope* it to a specific object of that class. I.e.

```
p.k();
```

would work perfectly in your code sample above.

The call

```
k();
```

would be fine inside an instance (nonstatic) method. And it would be equivalent to

```
this.k();
```

The implied `this` refers to the current instance of the class. Whenever the compiler sees an unqualified call like `k()` within an instance method, it will automatically scope it with `this.` . However, since static methods aren't tied to any instance of the class, you (and the compiler) can't refer to `this` inside a static method. Hence you need to explicitly name an instance of the class to call an instance method on.

Answer (score 5):

> Rules are simple:
>   1 - Static method cannot cannot call non-static methods.

That's simply not true. A static method *can* call a non-static method, just via a "target" reference. For example, this is fine in a static method:

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(10);
int y = x.intValue(); // Instance method!
```

The *real* point is "there's no `this` reference within a static method".

> 2 - Constructors are kind of a method with no return type.

That's not a really useful model, to be honest. It makes *more* sense (from the caller's point of view) to consider a constructor as a static method with a return type that's the same as the declaring class, but even that's not a perfect model by any means.

I suggest you think of a constructor as a different type of member. Embrace the differences between constructors and methods, instead of trying to hide them.

Comment: What do you think of likening the constructor to a void-returning callback that gets called as a part of object initialization? That level of indirection is a thing that, to my mind, escapes people and causes wrong assumptions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: It depends on whether you're thinking of it from the point of view of the *caller* (in which case "void-returning" is nonsense, as you can use the result) or the *implementation* (in which case it makes sense). I prefer to just think of it as its own type of thing, rather than trying to make tortuous analogies to methods.

Comment: It is not nonsense if you factor in the fact that the caller is merely applying `new` and not calling any functions. That's in fact my main point -- one must respect `new`, not look through it. That operator's return value is the reference, and the constructor can still be seen as a `void`-returning callback. I agree that analogies can only go so far, but they still help when learning something new.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: From the simplest caller's point of view, they're calling the constructor and it's returning a reference. I see no reason to make it any more complex than that (again, from the caller's point of view)... and I consider viewing it as a callback to *be* more complex.

Comment: But they are also calling all the initialization code outside the constructor. This really comes to the level of your intuition -- when you are already an experienced programmer, you'll never miss those aspects, but when you are just starting to learn, the precise definitions are more important.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If we're going to talk about precise definitions, then I have to point out that `new` is *not* an operator - not according to the language specification. I completely agree that precise definitions are important - which is why I think it's simpler to treat constructors as "something different" rather than trying to make analogies. It's easier to be precise if you don't have to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Yes, it's the *instance creation expression*, if I remember correctly :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Class instance creation expression :)