# Confusion about static keyword

Tags: java, oop, static

I just read in a document that "A static method can call only other static methods and can not call a non-static method from it". But when I tried to test it I think saw something different.

I have a class C which is described below

```
import pckage1.*;

public class C
{

public static void main(String par[])
{       
}
public static void cc() 
{
    A ob = new A();
    ob.accessA(0);      
}   

}
```

where class A is

```
package pckage1;

public class A 
{
public A() 
{
}
public void accessA(int x)
{   
}

}
```

Now here from cc STATIC method in class C, a NON STATIC method accessA() is called. How could that be possible if the statement about static method is true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method access to non-static constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513633/static-method-access-to-non-static-constructor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *A static method can call only other static methods and can not call a non-static method from it*

That's **wrong**.

Static methods *can* call non-static methods as long as they have objects to call the methods *on* (as you discovered in your code snippet). How else would a non-static method *ever* be called?

You **can't** do `nonStaticFoo()` from a static method, since it is interpreted as `this.nonStaticFoo()` and since there is no `this` available in a static method.

Very similar question from earlier today:

- [Static method access to non-static constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513633/static-method-access-to-non-static-constructor/10513675#10513675)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call a non-static method of your Class.

Try with this :

```
import pckage1.*;

public class C
{

public static void main(String par[])
{       
}
public static void cc() 
{
    A ob = new A();
    ob.accessA(0);  
    print();    
}   

public void print() 
{

}   
}
```

It won't work, because you're callign a non-static method from a static method, and you don't have an instance of the C class to work with in your static method.

Answer (score 2):

Since every Java program starts executing from a static method, if the statement you cite were true, there would have been no way for any Java program to ever execute an instance method!

Answer (score 2):

A static method has no default context in C, and not `this`.

However any method can use an intsnace of a class to call a method.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling an instance method, on an instance--you're not trying to call an instance method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an instance of class A and call a method on it.
So the method you are calling is instance method (not static method).
But you cannot call a non static method of class C.